# Finding Partition, Riemanns Integral

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, riemann-sum

Define $f:[0,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(x)=1$ if $x\not=1$ and $f(1)=3$. Find a partition $D$ of $[0,2]$ for which $S_D-s_D<2^{-1000}$.

Answer (score 0):

Then partition $P$ will have only four points:
$$
t_=0,\,\,t_1=1-\delta,\,\,t_2=1+\delta,\,\,t_3=2.
$$
Clearly
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=3\cdot 2\delta-1\cdot 2\delta=4\delta.
$$
Hence you need
$$
0<\delta<2^{1002}.
$$